# didBegin(contact) is only called once

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am making a game and I am calling a function several times that adds a node to the scene.

I need to know if the node touches the player. The problem is that the `didBegin(contact)` method is called only when the first instance of the node touches the player node but it is not called when the other instances that are called touch it.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let circlePlayer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    circlePlayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y:
    self.frame.minY + circlePlayer.size.height * 3)

    circlePlayer.zPosition = 2

    //Physics for player

    circlePlayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:
    circlePlayer.size.height / 2)
    circlePlayer.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsNumbering.player
    circlePlayer.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =
    PhysicsNumbering.star

    //Star node is called multiple times
    let star = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(starEmitter), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)])

 }
```

This is the Star Node function:

```
func starEmitter(){

    let star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "15")

    //Physics World
    star.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: star.size.height / 2)
    star.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsNumbering.star
    star.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsNumbering.player
    star.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    star.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    star.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    star.zPosition = 0

    let tooMuch = self.frame.maxX

    let point1 = UInt32(tooMuch)


    star.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(point1 * 2)) - CGFloat(point1)  ,y: self.frame.maxY )

    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.frame.minY + 100, duration: 1.4)
    let removeNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move,removeNode])

    star.run(sequence)
    addChild(star)
}
```

And this is the `didBeginContact` method:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var BodyOne = SKPhysicsBody()
    var BodyTwo = SKPhysicsBody()


    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask{
        BodyOne = contact.bodyA
        BodyTwo = contact.bodyB
    }
    else{
        BodyOne = contact.bodyB
        BodyTwo = contact.bodyA
    }

    //------------------------------------



    if BodyTwo.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.player && BodyOne.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.star{


        let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(by: 1.3, duration: 0.5)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1)
        let removeNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        BodyOne.node?.removeAllActions()
        let group = SKAction.group([scaleUp,fadeOut])
        BodyOne.node?.run(SKAction.sequence([group,removeNode]))
        print("star touched")
    }


}
```

I tried to search it online but could not find the reason why this might happen. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: where you put your first chunk of code? and what is the use of this line of code:     **let star = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(starEmitter), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)])** .

Comment: delete all codes in **didBegin** method and try this conditions instead, observe whether the contacts are made : **if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.Player  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.Star) { print("Player touched Stars")   } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.Star  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsNumbering.Player) { print("Player also touches Stars") }**

Comment: I found the problem. I had a few logical errors in my code. Once I fixed them . The above code worked